# Tkinter grid: Use new column on current row for new widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I program a GUI in Python3 with Tkinter and place widgets with `.grid()`. How can i tell Tkinter to place a new widget on the same row as the last placed widget but on a new, specified, column. The problem is that Tkinter automatically uses the next row when i don't specify the row and i don't want to hardcode the row number or pollute my code with a row counter that i have to increment every time i insert a widget in column 0.

**What i tried:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Label(root, text="Label 0").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 1").grid(column=1)
Label(root, text="Label 2").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 3").grid(column=1)
Label(root, text="Label 4").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 5").grid(column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

**How the layout looks like**

```
Label 0
        Label 1
Label 2
        Label 3
Label 3
        Label 5
```

**How the layout should look like**

```
Label 0 Label 1
Label 2 Label 3
Label 3 Label 5
```

**What i don't want**

It is possible to achieve the correct layout by specify the column number, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Label(root, text="Label 0").grid(column=0,row=0)
Label(root, text="Label 1").grid(column=1,row=0)
Label(root, text="Label 2").grid(column=0,row=1)
Label(root, text="Label 3").grid(column=1,row=1)
Label(root, text="Label 4").grid(column=0,row=2)
Label(root, text="Label 5").grid(column=1,row=2)
root.mainloop()
```

But that is not flexible and inserting something in the second row means the code for all following rows have to be changed. Adding a row counter is possible, but this is error prone since it is easy to forget to increase the counter. Is there a way to insert a new widget on the second column on the same row as the last inserted widget without hardcoding or keep track of the last row number?

Or is there a function that returns the row of the last inserted widget? So that i can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Label(root, text="Label 0").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 1").grid(column=1,row=<root.unknowFunctionToGetTheLastInsertedRow>)
Label(root, text="Label 2").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 3").grid(column=1,row=<root.unknowFunctionToGetTheLastInsertedRow>)
Label(root, text="Label 4").grid(column=0)
Label(root, text="Label 5").grid(column=1,row=<root.unknowFunctionToGetTheLastInsertedRow>)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the documentation for the underlying Tk `grid` command, and it's *vastly* more convenient to use than the provided Python wrapper, since you can call it on multiple widgets at once (in which case they're given successive column numbers in a new row).  You'd hardly ever need to supply an explicit row or column number.  Here's an example of how you could use `grid` in this style from Python:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.tk.call('grid',
    Label(root, text="Label 0"),
    Label(root, text="Label 1")
)
root.tk.call('grid',
    Label(root, text="Label 2"),
    Label(root, text="Label 3")
)
root.tk.call('grid',
    Label(root, text="Label 4"),
    Label(root, text="Label 5")
)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Other options you can pass to `grid` when used in this manner: `"x"` to leave a grid cell empty, `"-"` to increase columnspan of the widget to the left, `"^"` to increase rowspan of the widget above.

Comment: While I think you're right that the underlying `grid` command is more powerful than the python wrapper, your example seems very confusing. You're showing each column as a row which makes it very hard to visualize the layout by looking at the code. It would look better if the items which were side-by-side visually were also side-by-side in the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I see your point, but I'd think that most real-world widgets are going to have enough options specified that you wouldn't be able to fit more than one on a line.